# How can I make my pendrive a Removable Disc again

Tags: diskpart

I created a partition primary in my pendrive to boot and install Windows 8, but now I want to undo this process... when I open My Computer, my pendrive is a Fixed Disc, not a Removable Disc(default)...
How can I make my pendrive a Removable Disc again?

commands used to create partition primary:

```
DISKPART > List Disk  
DISKPART > Select Disk 2 (pendrive)  
DISKPART > Clean  
DISKPART > Create partition primary  
DISKPART > Active  
DISKPART > Format fs=fat32 quick
```

Comment: are you booting off of the pendrive still?

Comment: no, I just used it to install my Windows 8